# Core stucks in blocking handler STM32F103C8T6 libopencm3

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, debugging

I have problem with my STM and the libopencm3. After the reset handler is called, there is immediately jump into blocking handler.

I suppose that the hard fault occurs.

Here is the call stack:

```
??@0x07fffd545 
<signal handler called>@0xfffffff9
reset_handler@0x0800017a
```

And the linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
    rom (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K
    ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K
}

/* Enforce emmition of the vector table. */
EXTERN (vector_table)

/* Define the entry point of the output file. */
ENTRY(reset_handler)

/* Define sections. */
SECTIONS
{
    .text : {
        *(.vectors) /* Vector table */
        *(.text*)   /* Program code */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.rodata*) /* Read-only data */
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >rom

    /* C++ Static constructors/destructors, also used for __attribute__
     * ((constructor)) and the likes */
    .preinit_array : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __preinit_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
        __preinit_array_end = .;
    } >rom
    .init_array : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __init_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array))
        __init_array_end = .;
    } >rom
    .fini_array : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __fini_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.fini_array))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        __fini_array_end = .;
    } >rom

    /*
     * Another section used by C++ stuff, appears when using newlib with
     * 64bit (long long) printf support
     */
    .ARM.extab : {
        *(.ARM.extab*)
    } >rom
    .ARM.exidx : {
        __exidx_start = .;
        *(.ARM.exidx*)
        __exidx_end = .;
    } >rom

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;

    .data : {
        _data = .;
        *(.data*)   /* Read-write initialized data */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _edata = .;
    } >ram AT >rom
    _data_loadaddr = LOADADDR(.data);

    .bss : {
        *(.bss*)    /* Read-write zero initialized data */
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = .;
    } >ram

    /*
     * The .eh_frame section appears to be used for C++ exception handling.
     * You may need to fix this if you're using C++.
     */
    /DISCARD/ : { *(.eh_frame) }

    . = ALIGN(4);
    end = .;
}

PROVIDE(_stack = ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram));
```

How can I debug what causes this error?

Comment: Most likely linker script is not the issue, unless problem happened if linker script got modified. Most likely cause is wrong compiler settings which outputs wrong opcodes for the processor, or the startup code is for another processor, or some C code that the startup code calls is faulty.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for your's hint. The -mthumb compiler flag was missing. I didn't know that the ARM arch can support more that one instruction set. Long story short - M-profile processors execute T32 (formerly Thumb) instructions. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0774f/chr1385546391098.html